# MST in unDirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

i have an undricted graph G=(V,E) and weight function w:E->R+. also, i have the MST T of G.

I have to build an algorithm that does the follow:
if we add a new edge e' that has the weight w(e') to E. suggest an algorithm that updates T in a way that it will be MST of the new graph G'=(V,EUe').
complexity: O(V).

what i suggested is:

1) Add e' to T. we get a new graph call it T' that include one cycle.
2) Run DFS on T' and mark every vertex that you visit. and in addition save
   every vertex and every edge weight in stacks.
3) When we visit a vertex that we already visited we stop running.
4) and start withdrawing from the stack till we get to the vertex we stopped at.
5) while withdrawing we save the maximum edge weight we withdraw ed from the
   stack.
6) if the maximum edge weight is bigger that w(e') we replace them.
7) otherwise we remain with the same T.

i hope it's clear.
i would be very grateful if anyone could till me if it works or give me other
solutions and suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the solution you suggested is correct because a graph with the same number of edges and nodes (like T) consists of a simple cycle with trees rooted at some (maybe none) of the nodes of this cycle.

You need to delete exactly 1 edge from T such that the remaining graph is still connected. Obviously the best choice is to delete the largest edge. The only edges you can delete while keeping the graph connected are the ones in the cycle (the ones you are adding to the stack).

Another solution would be to find the [bridges](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/) in the graph, then finding the maximum non-bridge edge and deleting it. However since this is a special graph the solution you mentioned would be much easier (the non-bridge edges are the ones on the cycle) .